# Getting errors on trying to use javascript latest features

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade to use the latest version of javascript by install babel 7 and the associated presets by i keep getting an error when using asyn/await syntax, the error is: **ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined**

package.json

```
   "keywords": [],
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
   "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
   "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
   "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
   "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
   "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
   "babel-watch": "^7.0.0",
   "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
```

.babelrc:

```
{
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=referenceerror%3A+regeneratorRuntime+is+not+defined&rlz=1C1NHXL_enCA756CA756&oq=referenceerror%3A+regeneratorRuntime+is+not+defined&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.9097337j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8